# ftd2xx python library doesn't work in raspberry pi

Tags: pi-4, python-3, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have installed Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software(bullseye). I tried `pip install ftd2xx`. The installation was complete. I have used the library in windows and developed an program. Now I want to use the same program in raspberry pi 4.

I followed the procedure from official FTDI's [youtube installation guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jynlynjOOek). But when I try to import ftd2xx in python the error is

```
 libftd2xx.so: cannot open shared object file
```

Edit 1: After following comments of [@uKBaz](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/121848/ukbaz) I followed the readme document from the downloaded driver file. Later when I tried to import ftd2xx in python the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ftd2xx/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .ftd2xx import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ftd2xx/ftd2xx.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _ftd2xx_linux as _ft
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ftd2xx/_ftd2xx_linux.py", line 1508, in <module>
    stime = _libraries['libftd2xx.so'].stime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so: undefined symbol: stime
```

Note: I have downloaded 1.4.24 ARMv7 hard-float and followed the instruction given in readme file to copy the library file and create symbolic link. The example file given with the download files work fine.

Comment: There is the following blog where someone had the same issue: https://iosoft.blog/2018/12/05/ftdi-python-part-2/ . They solved the problem by switching to https://pypi.org/project/pylibftdi/

Comment: I tried the first link. It doesn't resolve. I would like to use the same code, so I would prefer to use ftd2xx library itself.

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have the shared object `libftd2xx.so` installed. You can find the install instructions at: https://ftdichip.com/document/installation-guides/

Comment: have tried it. But doesn't help. The example given in the guide is working. but when I try to import ftd2xx I still get the same error

Comment: Can you update your question with more details on what you have done. For example have you update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or put `libftd2xx.so` in to standard library directories on Linux?

Comment: I have used `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which has caused a new error

Comment: Did you follow the `Installing the D2XX shared library and static library` instructions in the `ReadMe.txt` of the package you downloaded from ftdichip?  Is there `libftd2xx.so` in `/usr/local/lib`? Did you copy the `.h` files?

Comment: I have copied the libftd2xx.so.1.4.24 file to `/usr/local/lib` and created symbolic link. Have done ldconfig. Have also copied the header files to `/usr/local/lib`. yeah I followed the readme.txt

Comment: You mean you copied the header files to `/usr/local/include`?

Comment: yes i did. Sorry its `/usr/local/include` for .h files

Comment: I have changed to Buster OS and it is working good.